# Why is it safer to run as non-root inside a single-user container that is deployed with rootless podman?

Tags: container

According to the [JellyFin documentation](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/installation/container/)

> Podman doesn't require root access to run containers, although there are some details to be mindful of; see the relevant documentation. For security, the Jellyfin container should be run using rootless Podman. Furthermore, **it is safer to run as a non-root user within the container.** The `--user` option will run with the provided user id and group id inside the container. The `--userns keep-id` flag ensures that current user's id is mapped to the non-root user's id inside the container. This ensures that the permissions for directories bind-mounted inside the container are mapped correctly between the user running Podman and the user running Jellyfin inside the container.

This seems like a lot more work. What are they actually getting by deploying a rootless container to run as a non-root user? What attack are they mitigating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a defense in depth solution.

The fake root in the container still kinda acts like a root user. Using a normal user mitigates the additional privileges and makes it so your apps have normal user perms.

Or to put it in other words:

- it adds a step to do before your system is comprised by a attacker.

Instead of just having to get a reverse shell. Now they also have to gain elevated permissions. And that’s before they can start breaking out of the container.

Comment: Can you explain this. Can you show a historical or theoretical container break out exploit that required root inside a rootless container and could not have executed by a non-root user inside the container?

Comment: For example the technique used here. https://juggernaut-sec.com/docker-breakout-lpe/#Scenario_3_Getting_a_Foothold_Directly_in_a_Non-Privileged_Container

Comment: great example, pretty contrived (requires the unprivledged docker container to be granted cap_sys_admin) but still. That's a great addition.